# Get all messages and replies from Microsoft teams channel - Graph paging

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using the script that has been published on this website [https://myteamsday.com/2019/10/08/exporting-team-channel-messages/][1]

which exports channel messages to a OneNote file  .the script works fine, My issue and question is that I can not add paging to the script ( in order to retrieve all messages using "@odata.nextLink") I am a newbie in developing and MS graph, I know that I need to add an if statement or While() to the code but I am not sure how to do that.

Here is where the script reads all messages and replies and writes them to a Onenote file

```html
$messagesURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/" + $teamID + "/channels/" + $ChannelID + "/messages"
$graphResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $messagesURI  -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $delegatedaccessToken"}
#go through files and copy them to target

foreach ($message in $graphResponse.value)
{
$messageID = $message.id 
$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '<p>' + $message.createdDateTime+" "+ $message.from.user.displayName +" <b>" + $message.subject+"</b>:"+$message.body.content +'</p>'
$repliesURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/" + $teamID + "/channels/" + $ChannelID + "/messages/" + $messageID + "/replies"
$repliesResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $repliesURI  -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $delegatedaccessToken"}
foreach ($reply in $repliesResponse.value ) {
$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ' + $reply.createdDateTime+" reply: "+ $reply.from.user.displayName +" " + $reply.subject+":"+$reply.body.content +'</p>'
}
$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '<p>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>'

}

$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '  </body>
</html>
'

$graphResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $addPageURL -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $delegatedaccessToken"} -Body $pageHtml -ContentType "text/html"
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not add paging to the script", Could you please elaborate what you want to try here?

Comment: how to add paging in order to retrieve more than 999 messages from the channel, in the cases that graph replies multiple pages pf data : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Comment: You cannot retrieve more than 999 in a single request. You should be using @nextlink and make the call to get the next set of messages :)-

Comment: Thanks, that`s my question :) not sure where in the code I need to add that? and how any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here first I am making the call and then I get the 20 messages with nextLink. Taking that nextLink I am just using a while loop where nextLink is not null and calling the API with that nextLink again and saving the result in $result variable. Try below code, it worked for me.

```
$result= $null
$messagesURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/" + $teamID + "/channels/" + $ChannelID + "/messages"
$graphResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $messagesURI  -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $delegatedaccessToken"}
while($graphResponse."@odata.nextLink" -ne $null)
{
$result = $result + $graphResponse."value"
$graphResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $graphResponse."@odata.nextLink"  -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $delegatedaccessToken"}
}
$result = $result + $graphResponse."value"
#go through files and copy them to target

foreach ($message in $result)
{
$messageID = $message.id 
$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '<p>' + $message.createdDateTime+" "+ $message.from.user.displayName +" <b>" + $message.subject+"</b>:"+$message.body.content +'</p>'
$repliesURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/" + $teamID + "/channels/" + $ChannelID + "/messages/" + $messageID + "/replies"
$repliesResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $repliesURI  -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $delegatedaccessToken"}
foreach ($reply in $repliesResponse.value ) {
$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ' + $reply.createdDateTime+" reply: "+ $reply.from.user.displayName +" " + $reply.subject+":"+$reply.body.content +'</p>'
}
$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '<p>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>'

}

$pageHtml = $pageHtml + '  </body>
</html>
'

$graphResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $addPageURL -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $delegatedaccessToken"} -Body $pageHtml -ContentType "text/html"
```

Comment: @Aysan Just updated $result instead of $graphResponse.value in for loop. Please verify.

Comment: Thank you! I received this error message :null : The term 'null' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Temp\Channel2OneNote - rev2.ps1:70 char:10
+ $result= null
+          ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (null:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Try it in powershell :)-

Comment: Solved the issue, the problem was happening as the result of the $result= null in the code snippet you provided, changed it to $result = $null and it sorted it out. I really appreciate your help